# elasticsearch time query for hour of the day

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch python client.

I have a date range field in my index. I want docs between 12pm to 2pm. So, This is the query I wrote,

```
query = {"query":"filter": [{"range" : { "status_time_frame" : {"gte" : "10/11/2017","lte" : "13/11/2017", "relation":"within"}}}],{"script":{"source": "doc.status_time_frame.status_time_frame.getHourOfDay() >= min && doc.status_time_frame.status_time_frame.getHourOfDay() <= max","params": {"min":12,"max":14}}}}
```

But it is giving me syntax error when I try to run it.

```
  File "vehicle-report-query-elastic.py", line 3
    query = {"query":{"filter": [{"range" : { "status_time_frame" : {"gte" : "10/11/2017","lte" : "13/11/2017", "relation":"within"}}}],{"script":{"source": "doc.status_time_frame.status_time_frame.getHourOfDay() >= min && doc.status_time_frame.status_time_frame.getHourOfDay() <= max","params": {"min":12,"max":14}}}}}

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need ro remove `relation: within` from your `range` query

Comment: I did, still gives me the syntax error.

Comment: You're also missing an open curly brace before `"filter"`

Comment: @Val bro thanks for your replies and help. But I still get the error. I had tried everything. Can you write full query in an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct query should look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filter": [
      {
        "range": {
          "status_time_frame": {
            "gte": "10/11/2017",
            "lte": "13/11/2017"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc.status_time_frame.status_time_frame.getHourOfDay() >= min && doc.status_time_frame.status_time_frame.getHourOfDay() <= max",
          "params": {
            "min": 12,
            "max": 14
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```