# Is it possible to search by daily time range between dates?

Tags: elasticsearch, time, range, aggregate

I can use aggregate to make some stats between two timestamps as following:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "ok"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "deviceId": "123456789"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": 1669852800,
              "lt": 1671062400
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "results": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "fixed_interval": "60",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to query the results contain specific time range daily only? For example, 7am - 9am daily between Dec.1 to Dec.15. How to achieve it?

Comment: do you want to group result based on time range or you want to just retrive result for specific time range ?

Comment: I just want to retrieve result for specific time range

Comment: ok.. are you storng time in seperatefield or it is part of dat field itself ?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47271666/5489276) answer written by Val and it will work for your scenario as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elasticsearch time query for hour of the day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270824/elasticsearch-time-query-for-hour-of-the-day)

Comment: @segar
we only have 1 field - time and the format is date - epoch-millis.

Comment: did you check the above Val answer link ? I am sure that it will work for your usecase as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on elasticsearch v7.15.2 as following:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "ok"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "deviceId": "123456789"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": 1669852800,
              "lt": 1671062400
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc.time.value.getHourOfDay() >= params.min && doc.time.value.getHourOfDay() < params.max",
              "params": {
                "min": 8,
                "max": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "results": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "fixed_interval": "60"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The syntax is slightly different from the comment above, but it works.